# sliding panel did't close on link click

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have one slide panel login box with jquery and its works fine only close link did't work
 here is javascript code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login-link").click(function(){
        $("#login-panel").slideToggle(200);
    })
})
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $("#login-panel").hide(0);
    }

});

$("#login-close").click(function() {
$("#login-panel").hide(0);
return false;
});

</script>
```

here is HTML for

```
<a id="login-link" href="#" title="Login">Login</a>   
<div id="login-panel">
<div style="padding-left:10px;width:190px; height:163px; background-color:#2a2a2a; text-align:left; vertical-align:text-top;">
<form id="login" action="<?php echo osc_base_url(true) ; ?>" method="post">
<table border="0" style="font: normal 10pt Tahoma; color:#fff;">
  <tr>
    <td height="20" valign="top">Email <br>
    <input id="email" type="text" value="" name="email"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="20" valign="top">Password<br>
    <input id="password" type="password" value="" name="password">
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="25" valign="top">
     <small><a href="#login-close">press ESC or close</a></small></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

it works perfect and also close the login box when i **ESC** is pressed.
but it did't close on link click, it only add **#login-close** in url

Thanks

Comment: You don't have any element with an id of `login-close`...

Comment: It is adding #login-close to the url because you did not `return false` at the end of the onclick handler. This causes the browser to navigate to the link.

Comment: add id element to anchor tag <a href="#login-close" id="login-close">press ESC or close</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any element with an id of login-close. Try change your close anchor to this:

```
<a href="#login-close" id="login-close">press ESC or close</a>
```

Also, make sure *all* your code is inside the document ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login-link").click(function(){
        $("#login-panel").slideToggle(200);
    });

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
            $("#login-panel").hide(0);
        }
    });

    $("#login-close").click(function() {
        $("#login-panel").hide(0);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
$("#login-close").click(function(e) { // added e to function arguments
    e.preventDefault(); // added method here
    $("#login-panel").hide(0);
    // remove return false here.
});
```

Also add an id to the link:

```
<a id="login-close" href="#login-close">press ESC or close</a>
```

You've got mistakes in your JS (not everything is in the ready function) and HTML (unclosed tags) - http://jsfiddle.net/dtctu/

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give an id to your link, so `$("#login-close")` can't find it.

Add `id="login-close"` to your link.

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/WhSTh/5/

`id` login-close was missing: Also I added `<td>` which was missing as well:

```
<td height="25" valign="top">
    <small><a href="#login-close" id="login-close"> press ESC or close</a></small>
</td>
```

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login-link").click(function() {
        $("#login-panel").slideToggle(200);
    })
})
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $("#login-panel").hide(0);
    }

});

$("#login-close").click(function() {
    $("#login-panel").hide(0);
    return false;
});​
```